# Blank screen after splash in react native eas build, how to debug?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

My app runs well in expo go but when I create a apk with eas build it shows a blank screen after splash screen. I created apk with expo 45 build, it was fine.

{
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web",
"eject": "expo eject",
"test": "jest --watchAll"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "jest-expo"
},
"dependencies": {
"@expo/samples": "~36.0.0",
"@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"expo": "^47.0.8",
"expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
"expo-asset": "^8.7.0",
"expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
"expo-dev-client": "~2.0.1",
"expo-file-system": "~15.1.1",
"expo-font": "~11.0.1",
"expo-intent-launcher": "^10.3.1",
"expo-localization": "~14.0.0",
"expo-sqlite": "~11.0.0",
"expo-updates": "^0.15.6",
"expo-web-browser": "~12.0.0",
"i18next": "^22.4.5",
"js-base64": "3.7.3",
"native-base": "^3.4.25",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-dom": "18.1.0",
"react-i18next": "^12.1.1",
"react-native": "0.70.5",
"react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
"react-native-fontawesome": "^7.0.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
"react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
"react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
"react-native-screens": "~3.18.2",
"react-native-svg": "^13.4.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
"react-native-view-pdf": "^0.14.0",
"react-native-web": "0.18.10",
"react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
"react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.5",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.1",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.0",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.3",
"watchman": "^1.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
"@types/react": "~18.0.26",
"babel-preset-expo": "~9.2.2",
"jest-expo": "^47.0.1",
"typescript": "~4.9.4"
},
"private": true
}